# Websockets on Android Unity devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket

I am new to websockets, and I have some doubts that I would like you to clarify, but first of all I would like to tell you what is the aim of the project:

I have a server (Android Tablet) that will share its Wifi through Wifi zone. And other devices (Android mobiles) will connect to that Tablet. Throughout the execution, it will be sending messages (strings) between the server and the client.

1.- Would it be possible to make this communication with websockets?

2.- Is it possible in unity to automatically obtain the ip of the server to make an instant connection?

3.- In case the above mentioned is possible, any suggestions?

Thanks and greetings

Comment: 1. yes
2. use either bonjour or similar discovery protocol, or just udp broadcasts to notify clients
3. good luck

Comment: know of any pages or examples that I can start to build upon?

Comment: start with generic websockets, there isn't much difference at all between pc and android when it comes to network conectivity . this is hardly a polished example and has serious bloat but you may want to check out https://github.com/zambari/WSFrameworkTemplateAlpha

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but... My understanding is that you need Unity Pro to get WebSockets support, at least for Android (not sure about iOS). See [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mobile-websocket-unity-free-android-ios.190091/) for more information and a possible alternative solution on the Asset Store.